# Spring Data Rest - @JsonDeserializer is never used

Tags: spring-data-rest

I want to be able to post something like this

```
{
  ...
  "foo": "http://localhost:8081/foos/2",
  ...
}
```

but want to store only the 2 as a Long in the database. Therefore, I created a JsonDeserializer and declared the field like this:

```
@JsonDeserialize(using = RestResourceURLSerializer.class)
private Long foo;
```

The RestResourceURLSerializer looks like this: (not really important, I think, but to give a complete picture)

```
public class RestResourceURLSerializer extends JsonDeserializer<Long> {

    @Override
    public Long deserialize(JsonParser p, DeserializationContext ctxt) throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
        URL url = p.readValueAs(URL.class);
        String path = url.getPath();
        return Long.parseLong(path.substring(path.lastIndexOf('/') + 1));
    }

}
```

My problem is that I get this error message posting an entity: https://pastebin.com/JszRnaCc

```
Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidFormatException: Cannot deserialize value of type `java.lang.Long` from String "http://localhost:8081/foos/2": not a valid Long value
 at [Source: (org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteInputStream); line: 1, column: 2935] (through reference chain: com.demo.Bar["foo"])
```

Interestingly, I have a different entity in the same project that does the same thing and is not having these issues. Any ideas how to troubleshoot?

Comment: See the [doc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/rest/docs/current/reference/html/#representations) about how to register custom serializer and deserializer in Spring Data REST

Comment: Do they still need to be registered when I explicitly set it in the annotation?